# How to find WebSphere 8.5 Admin console URL in Linux

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I installed WebSphere 8.5 on Redhat Linux using the below steps.

```
1. Unzip the installation kit (WAS_V8.5_1_OF_3.zip, WAS_V8.5_2_OF_3.zip & WAS_V8.5_3_OF_3.zip)
2. Login as normal user
3. Navigate to the folder WLP/wlp-8500.jar
4. Install thru Running: 'java -jar wlp-8500.jar'
5. Follow the steps and complete installation (all comand line)
6. Move to wlp folder
7. Create server instance thru Moving to bin folder and Run 'server create <serverName>'
7. Start server thru Running 'server start <serverName>'
8. Check the server status thru Running 'server status <serverName>'
```

After this setup I created and started the server. It is up and running.
I dont know how to login to Admin console. I tried different URLs and ports nothing is working.

http://localhost:9060/ibm/console
http://localhost:9080/ibm/console

How to find the Admin Console URL or Port no?

Answer (score 7):

You have installed WebSphere Liberty Profile (wlp) not the full (aka classic) WebSphere Application Server. WebSphere Liberty doesn't have full administrative console like classic one. You have only simplified adminCenter feature, which must be installed separately.

The Admin Center is a web user interface that runs on Liberty profile V8.5.5.2 and later servers, since you have 8.5.0.0 version looking at your log, you will have to install later version to see it.

See also:

- [AdminCenter feature](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.adminCenter-1.0)
- [Settig up AdminCenter in Liberty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_ui_setup.html%23twlp_ui_setup__uiinstall?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-3-0)
- AdminCenter on youtube - [Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrePFmkFXG4), [New features (03/2015)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtQKv1Aa3e0)

If you want full administrative console, you have to use Installation Manager and install WebSphere Application Server, not the Liberty profile.

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell you the default ports you may have changed them:

http : 9060

https: 9043

To find the exact port:

Open WC_profiledir/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt
Look for lines similar to the following:

Administrative console port: 9102
Administrative console secure port: 9104

Comment: Yes, this is the right place WC_profiledir/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt